# Let X be an exponentially distributed random variable with parameter $\beta$. Compute $E(X^8)$. Show your work.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm preparing for a final exam, and currently trying to figure out if my solution to this question is correct, I would greatly appreciate any input. Below is what I've tried:

Since the the exponential distribution is a special case of the gamma distribution with $\alpha=1$, we can write derive the general case $E(X^{k})$:

$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^{k}\cdot x^{\alpha-1} \cdot e^{-x/\beta}}{\Gamma(\alpha) \cdot \beta^{\alpha}} dx$ = $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^{k+\alpha-1} \cdot e^{-x/\beta}}{\Gamma(\alpha) \cdot \beta^{\alpha}} dx$

We now want to manipulate the expression inside the integral in order to obtain an area equal to one. We do the following:

$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^{k+\alpha-1} \cdot e^{-x/\beta}}{\Gamma(\alpha) \cdot \beta^{\alpha}} dx$ = $\frac{\Gamma(\alpha + k) \cdot \beta^{k}}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^{k+\alpha-1} \cdot e^{-x/\beta}}{\Gamma(\alpha + k) \cdot \beta^{\alpha + k}} dx$

Since the area inside the integral is equal to one, we arrive at:

$E(X^{k}) = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + k) \cdot \beta^{k}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}$

With this result, we now try $E(X^8)$:

$E(X^8) = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + 8) \cdot \beta^{8}}{\Gamma(\alpha)} = \frac{\Gamma(9)\beta^{8}}{(0)!} = (8!) \beta^{8}$.

I am not sure I have performed this last part right. Is there another way to approach this?

Many thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expectation is
\begin{align*}
E[X^8]&= \int_0^\infty x^8\cdot\beta e^{-\beta x}\,dx\\
&=\beta\int_0^\infty x^{9-1}e^{\beta x}\,dx\\
&= \beta\cdot\frac{\Gamma(9)}{\beta^9} \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\Gamma(9)}\beta^9x^{9-1}e^{-\beta x}\,dx\\
&= 8!\cdot \beta^{-8}.
\end{align*}

---

Note: I take $X\sim\text{Exp}(\beta)$ to mean, 
$$f_X(x) = \beta e^{-\beta x}.$$

If you mean $f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\beta}e^{-\frac{1}{\beta}x}$, then
\begin{align*}
E[X^8]&= \int_0^\infty x^8\cdot\frac{1}{\beta} e^{-\frac{1}{\beta} x}\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{\beta}\int_0^\infty x^{9-1}e^{\frac{1}{\beta} x}\,dx\\
&= \frac{1}{\beta}\cdot\beta^9\,\Gamma(9) \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\Gamma(9)}\left(\frac{1}{\beta}\right)^9x^{9-1}e^{-\beta x}\,dx\\
&= 8!\cdot \beta^{8}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

The following answers your exam question, and does not deal with your calculation. First a remark about the use of the parameter $\beta$. You are using the mean as the parameter, rather than the more common $\lambda$, with density function $\lambda e^{-\lambda t}$.

With that choice of parameter, the moment generating function of the exponential with parameter $\beta$ is $\dfrac{1}{1-\beta t}$.

The Maclaurin expansion of the mgf is $1+\beta t+\beta^2 t^2+\beta^3t^3+\cdots$.

It follows that $E(X^8)=8!\beta^8$.  This I think is easier than the integration, even if one has to derive the mgf of the exponential.